# Clear or Delete file from textField

Tags: javascript, php, yii

I am working with PHP's Yii framework and having issues clearing or deleting the uploaded file from the `textfield`. Currently, it will delete the content from the `fileField`, but can't get it to delete the `textfield`. Any ideas?

**UPDATE**
I can now clear my `textField` because I've hard coded my `clearFileInputField` function by adding `$('.getFile').val("");` I reference this in my `HTML` by adding the `'class' => 'getName'` in the `input` section. While this clears the data, it doesn't remove the file after saving. Any suggestions?

**HTML**

```
  <div id = "clearContent">
            <?php echo $form->labelex($model,'info'); ?>
            <?php echo $form->textfield($model,'info', array(placeholder => "No file chosen", readonly => true, 'class' => 'getName')); ?><br>
            <?php echo $form->fileField($model,'info'); ?>
            <?php echo $form->error($model,'info'); ?>

            <input type="checkbox" onclick = "clearFileInputField('clearContent')" href="javascript:noAction();"> Remove File
    </div>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
<script>
    function clearFileInputField(tagId) {
        document.getElementById(tagId).innerHTML = document.getElementById(tagId).innerHTML;
        $('.getFile').val("");
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Could you include the output of this `div` as generated by php? Also how does the `textfield` get set since it is read only?

Comment: Under the model rules, did u define 'info' as 'allowEmpty'=>true?

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure if I understood the problem you are having correctly. If I understood the question completely wrong, please elaborate and I will try to improve my answer.

---

If you want to remove the the content (the value attribute) of a text and file input you can use code like the following:

```
// listen to the click on the #clearnbtn element
document.getElementById('clearbtn').addEventListener('click', function() {
    // Remove the value of the #foo and #bar elements
    document.getElementById('foo').value = "";
    document.getElementById('bar').value = "";
});
```

If you would like to remove an entire field you can do that like so:

```
// Retrieves the input element, gets its parents and removes itself from it
var fooElement = document.getElementById('foo');
fooElement.parentElement.removeChild(fooElement)
```

Or you can set the `innerHTML` attribute of the parent element to an empty string (`''`).

```
document.getElementById('clearContent').innerHTML = "";
```

https://jsfiddle.net/osjk7umh/1/

Comment: Hi @Mike Rombout, thanks for your answer. However, this isn't exactly what I am looking for. Essentially, the entire process consists of selecting a file, saving that file, and then later being able to edit that file. I've updated my post, but my major issue is that I cannot delete or remove the selected file after saving. During edit mode, it clears the data, but it doesn't save.

Comment: So you want the users to be able to remove the file from the server? In that case you can use [`unlink()`](http://php.net/unlink) to remove the file from the server.